# Angular-Material is there some way md-sidenav and main content can both have focus

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material to implement a sliding nav bar using the `md-sidenav` directive.

*index.html*

```
<div flex>
  <md-content>
    <p>Here is content.</p>
    <a href="">Click Me</a><!-- I want to be able click this even when the sidenav is open!!! -->
  </md-content>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SideNavCtrl as sd">
  <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2"
   md-component-id="right"
   md-is-open="sd.rightSideBarOpen"
   md-sidenav-focus=>
    <md-content>
      <p>Side Nav content</p>
    </md-content>
  </md-sidenav>
</div>
```

This works great, but when the nav is open it takes two clicks to interact with the content in the main window. I understand this is the expected behaviour with the the Material stacked sheets paradigm, but it is not the behaviour I want for this project. Interestingly when the `md-is-locked-open` attribute is used, both the main content and the sidenav is in focus .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the backdrop with the following CSS:

```
md-backdrop.md-sidenav-backdrop {
  display: none;
}
```

Although you might want to open a ticket on Github requesting this functionality there as this may be something that should be built-in.

https://github.com/angular/material/issues

Answer (score 0):

to avoid loosing functionality of backdrop (eg hiding sidenav when clicked) it's better to use `background-color:transparent` than changing display property